# New in ubuntu 12 - taskbar

Tags: taskbar

I am new in ubuntu. I want to ask you. Can I somehow disable the launch panel and move these icons to the top taskbar?

And other one: Can I disable somehow touchpad? It doesn't disable while typing.. :(

Thank you.

Comment: The launcher can only be set to auto-hide. Its position cannot be changed.

Comment: If you have more questions please create a new entry, one question at a time.

Comment: There is no such thing as Ubuntu 12.

Answer (score 1):

About disabling the touchpad, go to System > Preferences > Mouse > Touchpad and check 'Disable touchpad while typing'. That sould do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot change the Left Hand panel besides auto hiding it and changing the size. You could change to another GUI but that is about it for Ubuntu

here is a guide to change the GUI although a simple google search will find others as well:
http://www.overclock.net/a/how-to-change-the-ubuntu-gui

System Settings > Mouse and Touchpad, has options options for hiding the mouse.

Good Luck!